# JAXB/XJC generates JAXBElement<String> rather than just String (to handle null case)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

Using JAXB/xjc shipped with JDK 1.7 (bin\xjc.exe)

Here's a snipped of my XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="NameType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Firstname" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Middlename" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The class generated shows:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Surname", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<String> surname;

public JAXBElement<String> getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.surname = value;
}
```

I understand JAXB is using JAXBElement to allow for null,but this makes no sense since anything declared as a String can be set to null.

And I don't have the option of changing the XSD, because my client would rather leave the existing XSD in production.

Question: Can I change the code generator to generate:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Surname", type = String.class, required = false)
protected String surname;

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String value) {
    this.surname = value;
}
```

Thanks
Joel

Answer (score 11):

By default a `JAXBElement` is generated when an XML element is both nillable and optional.

```
<xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

This is to allow you to construct XML the following scenarios:

1. The element should be absent from the XML document when the property is null.
2. The element should be present in the XML with a value of `xsi:nil="true"`when the property is a `JAXBElement` when the nil flag set.

To get rid of the `JAXBElement` you can use the `generateElementProperty` option as [answered by f1sh,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26549272/383861) but then you won't be able to handle both scenarios.

**For More Information**

See my answer to a related question:

- [Convert nil="true" to null during unmarshal operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519636/convert-nil-true-to-null-during-unmarshal-operation/12519783#12519783)

Comment: Thanks for the help Blaise. You rock sir.

Answer (score 6):

Check if you can pass arguments to your code generator (xjc). I had the same problem once but was able to solve the problem by setting `generateElementProperty` to false. [Here's how i did it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492257/how-to-write-a-java-client-to-access-wsdl-file/3493658#3493658)

This is definitely some option on the jaxb code generator and should be able to switch off.

EDIT:
According to `xjc.exe /?` you can spedify the bindings file with the `-b` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help F1sh. This does appear to work. I'll reply if there are further issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, it really solved the problem for me after several days of trying to find a solution!